# PHP - find and modifing image links as an string/DOM

Tags: php, regex, string, dom, find

I have buffered page via ob_get_contents to $content variable.
This content is loaded properly.

Now, from this string var I would like to extract all links related to images (accepting single and double quotes and format .png, .jpg, .jpeg., .gif, etc.) and check if these links have external path (http://server.com/path/). If true, save these files and replace external path to local (keep filename).

I tried simpliest way -> new DOCDocument - loadHTML($content), but I cant load DOM with proper (utf8) encoding (buffered string $content has proper charset, DOM no). I also tried html_entity, mb_encoding..., ->encoding('utf-8') etc. No effect.

`$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($content);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) { .... };`

Then I tried regex way (preg_match_all, str_replace, etc.), but needed regex formula is too diffucult for me. Could you advice me which way is best and how to make it? Thank you.

Comment: Extracting links from an HTML page? Definitely **DON'T** do it with RegEx if you can run a parser on the string.